# Google Actions build for M1 mac

Tags: actions-on-google

Can we get a gactions cli build for an M1 mac? The ones on https://developers.google.com/assistant/actionssdk/gactions and via npm don't work on the newer macbooks with M1 chips.

Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's more of a feature request than a question.

Comment: This question is not a programming question and should be closed. There is [an existing GitHub issue](https://github.com/actions-on-google/gactions/issues/3) on this subject to refer to. It's close to the end of the year, so you may need to wait a bit longer for a canonical response.